# Footer is not displaying in full page width using Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I checked **bootstrap.min.css** and **width:100%** is not mentioned for **navbar**, **navbar-inverse** and **navbar-fixed-top** classes but still it is displaying **100% width** for header section.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" >
    <div class="container">
        <div >
            <h3>Free Area</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

Similarly I want to display footer in **100% width** according to page width. I used below CSS and HTML code but it is not displaying **100% width** footer. So how can I make footer so it displays in entire width of page?

CSS

```
footer { margin: 0px 0; background:#006699; }
```

HTML

```
<footer>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row ">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h3>Section Area 01</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6">
                <h3>Section Area 02</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Link2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Are you by mistake putting the `<footer>` under `.container`? Kindly check. Would be better to debug if you could show us or link us to the full HTML.

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, sorry but I don't get your question of <footer> under .container? Can you please clarify it so I can reply you.

Comment: Okay, see the `<footer>` is directly under `<body>` or not. What's the parent of `<footer>`?

Comment: @Praveen Kumar, footer code is written in footer.php and it is included in other pages like about.php. So ultimately footer code is under container class in about.php.

Comment: Aha!!! Then you can't do anything... You need to bring the footer out of it... :( Sorry. Will you be able to edit it and bring it out? You can also close the other div while including the footer.

Comment: Is that possible or do you still want a CSS solution for this?

Comment: Yes, and I did it, now footer background color is displaying all over the page width. So it worked very well. One more quick question is that should I do same thing for header too? and thank you for your help about footer.

Comment: Header is already good right? :) Do you still want to mess around it? :)

Comment: Er... I thought navbar and header are the same. Aren't they? If not, go for it. Do it for header too. And yeah, enjoy your day! :)

Comment: Yes, header and navbar are same and it is good right now but was just curious to know. Can you please post your help as separate answer so I can accept it so it is helpful for other like me. Thank you again.

Comment: Sure, reopened, and now answering it. `:)`

Comment: How does it look? Good?

Comment: Hey, if the header and navbar looks good, don't mess it up please. :)

Comment: Lemme know if you have further questions.

Comment: yes, it is displaying fine so I will not mess it up like you advised. I am new to Bootstrap and was solving this issue for last 2 days but could not. But today you helped me much. It's not good to ask too much at once... hahaha...

Comment: Ha ha... That's okay... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [requested by the OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35226855/footer-is-not-displaying-in-full-page-width-using-bootstrap-3#comment58169393_35226855), the issue the OP is facing is, having either `<footer>` or `<header>` to be confined to the `width` of the `.container` of the Bootstrap framework. One best solution for this is to put the elements directly under the body.

So, your solution would be, replacing (probably) this old code:

```
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <header>
          <!-- Contents -->
        </header>
        <!-- Body -->
        <footer>
          <!-- Contents -->
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

To get it out of the `.container`, which limits the `width` and placing it directly under `<body>` like this:

```
<body>
  <header>
    <!-- Contents -->
  </header>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <!-- Body -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
    <!-- Contents -->
  </footer>
</body>
```